# Validate a Google Sheet before closing it or moving to another tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a google sheet where a user can change certain values and then press a button. Once the button is pressed, those entries are moved to other sheets based on the user selection using Google Apps Script.

Now I want to avoid the situation where the user has made the changes but didn't press the button and closed the sheet or moved to another sheet.
So is there an event that I can capture and validate the sheet before it is closed?

Thanks

Comment: You be the judge [here are the triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) available to you.

Comment: There is no `onClose` event. The only event that _might_ be helpful is `onEdit`, but I don't know how you would prompt the user without running constantly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding [Prompt dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs).

To evaluate the user's response, capture the return value for `prompt()`, then call [`PromptResponse.getResponseText()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response#getResponseText()) to retrieve the user's input, and compare the return value for [`PromptResponse.getSelectedButton()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response#getSelectedButton()) to the [`Ui.Button`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button) enum.

Here's a sample code:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show prompt', 'showPrompt')
      .addToUi();
}

function showPrompt() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.prompt(
      'Let\'s get to know each other!',
      'Please enter your name:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    ui.alert('Your name is ' + text + '.');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('I didn\'t get your name.');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('You closed the dialog.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One thing that can be done is that you can call the following every minute by a [time trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to see in which sheet the user is in:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var sheetName = sheet.getName()
```

If the user is in a different sheet you can validate your sheet.

Comment: What would happen if user closes the sheet? And I want to prevent the user from leaving the sheet and not validating it after user has moved out.